# Is there a analysis conjecture proven to be unprovable or a proof is non-existence?

Tags: analysis, math-history

Is there a analysis conjecture proven to be unprovable or a proof is non-existence?

So, is it once a math history milestone

Comment: why two downvote

Comment: There is a large number of assertions of analysis that have been proved independent of ZFC.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Maybe you could explain what is a ZFC in your answer.

Comment: @Victor Google "ZFC" and click the first result, which for me is the Wikipedia page on Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory (+ Choice). This is usually assumed to be the underpinning of mathematics. If you want to worry about provability, you should probably read that page.

Comment: Victor, did you mean to ask "why two upvotes"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a large number of statements in analysis that have been proved independent of the axioms of ZFC. For a partial list, [see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_undecidable_in_ZFC)  A fair number of them are questions that had already been asked, and worked on seriously, long before they were proved independent.

**Added:** ZFC is Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, with Axiom of Choice added. It is currently, and has been for quite a while, the standard "background theory" for most of mathematics.